# MVC: Route Get / Post to different controllers. How?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-routing

I am writing a MVC controller where I need to handle both, data return as well as a long poll "data has changed" like behavior from the SAME (!) url. NothingI can do about this - I am implementing a proxy for an already existing application, so I have no way to do any extensions / modifications to the API.

My main problem is:
* The POST operations have to be completed immediately.
* The GET operations take longer (can take hours sometimes).

Can I somehow rewrite both to go to different controllers? The alternative would be to... hm... make both async, just the POST is finishing right three and then.

Anyone a comment on that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should be able to use constraints at the routing level to control which controller/action the url goes to.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "route that matches only GETs for your url",
    "your url",
    new { controller = "some controller", action = "some action" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);

routes.MapRoute(
   "route that matches only POSTs for your url",
   "your url",
    new { controller = "some other controller", action = "some other action" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) That is what I was missing ;)

Comment: If each line is respectively prefixed with "name:", "url:", "defaults:" => what do you prefix the "new { httpMethod..." line with ?

Comment: @full_prog_full Prefix is just the name of the parameter in method declaration, which is `constraints` in this case.